# Compiling Python 3.7 with lambda expression can't find closed-over function

Tags: python

The following works and prints 42, as expected:

```
import textwrap
def test_compile():
    code_str = """
    def bump(x):
        return x + 1

    print(); print(bump(41))

    """
    dedented_code_str = textwrap.dedent(code_str)
    code_obj = compile(dedented_code_str, filename='<string>', mode='exec')
    exec(code_obj)
```

So, `dump` is defined when `print` is compiled and exec'd. Inserting a lambda expression, however, causes an exception from `exec`, namely that `bump` is not found (removing some lines for brevity):

> ```
> exec(code_obj)
> test_compile.py:48: 
> <string>:5: in <module>
> E   NameError: name 'bump' is not defined
> ```

Here is the offending attempt to compile:

```
import textwrap
def test_compile_with_lambda():
    code_str = """
    def bump(x):
        return x + 1

    debug_me = (lambda y: bump(y))(41)
    print(); print(debug_me)

    """
    dedented_code_str = textwrap.dedent(code_str)
    code_obj = compile(dedented_code_str, filename='<string>', mode='exec')
    exec(code_obj)
```

The subject-matter code, namely

```
def bump(x):
    return x + 1

debug_me = (lambda y: bump(y))(41)
print(); print(debug_me)
```

works in every other environment or context I have tried: at top level, as a script; inside an ordinary calling function (with `bump` defined either internally or externally to the ordinary calling function); and under pytest. I don't reproduce those cases here, to save space, but everything that one would intuitively expect to work seems to work. I expected that the lambda expression *should* be able to see `bump`, but the compiler disagrees.

Incidentally, if that subject-matter code is either invoked or compiled and (crucially) exec'd externally to but in the same file with `test_compile_with_lambda`, then `bump` is defined in the lambda expression and `test_compile_with_lambda` works. Presumably, in that case, the lambda expression refers to some `bump` other than the one that cohabits its source-code string.

I'd like to be able to compile what seem to me to be legal lambda expressions that refer to names appropriately defined in nearby contexts. Is it possible to make my `test_compile_with_lambda` work without defining `bump` in some unnatural way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your lambda expression creates a function with a free variable `bump`. There is no closure involved here.

When you execute the code, `bump` is looked up in the global scope, but `bump` is not defined in the global scope: it is defined in the local scope of `test_compile_with_lambda`.

To demonstrate this, pass the current *locals* as the global scope to `exec`.

```
import textwrap
def test_compile_with_lambda():
    code_str = """
    def bump(x):
        return x + 1

    debug_me = (lambda y: bump(y))(41)
    print(); print(debug_me)

    """
    dedented_code_str = textwrap.dedent(code_str)
    code_obj = compile(dedented_code_str, filename='', mode='exec')
    exec(code_obj, locals())
```

You will get the expected output of `42`.